# Google social login with Django + allauth + dj_rest_auth + Expo fails with "Error retrieving access token"

Tags: django, expo, google-signin, django-allauth, dj-rest-auth

We are using Django with a combination of allauth and `dj_rest_auth` as backend and `Expo` for building mobile frontend. We are currently facing an issue after logging in with Google Social Login.

After setting up the google console for IOS and adding the corresponding provider in django, we can retrieve the credentials from google such as `access_token`, `id_token` and `code`. We have an endpoint in our backend where we should send the `code` property. This endpoint calls the view that inherits from `SocialLoginView` (from dj_rest_auth).

When we are calling this endpoint with the corresponding `code` we are facing an issue that tells us:

```
allauth.socialaccount.providers.oauth2.client.OAuth2Error: Error retrieving access token: '{  "error": "invalid_request", "error_description": "You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure. You can let the app developer know that this app doesn't comply with one or more Google validation rules."}'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/allauth/socialaccount/providers/oauth2/client.py", line 93, in get_access_token
    raise OAuth2Error("Error retrieving access token: %s" % resp.content)
```

After some researches we saw that apparently the issue could come from a bad `redirect_uri`. Since there is no way to set redirect URI in the google cloud console (in IOS mode client console), we are actually blocked.